# Build hash of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hashtable

I'm new to using perl and I'm trying to build a hash of a hash from a tsv. My current process is to read in a file and construct a hash and then insert it into another hash.

```
   my %hoh = ();
   while (my $line = <$tsv>) 
   {
      chomp $line;
      my %hash;
      my @data = split "\t", $line;

      my $id;
      my $iter = each_array(@columns, @data);

      while(my($k, $v) = $iter->())
      {
         $hash{$k} = $v;
         if($k eq 'Id')
         {
            $id = $v;   
         }
      }

      $hoh{$id} = %hash;
   }
   print "dump: ", Dumper(%hoh);
```

This outputs:

```
dump
$VAR1 = '1234567890';
$VAR2 = '17/32';
$VAR3 = '1234567891';
$VAR4 = '17/32';
.....
```

Instead of what I would expect:

```
dump
{
   '1234567890' => { 
                    'k1' => 'v1',
                    'k2' => 'v2',
                    'k3' => 'v3',
                    'k4' => 'v4',
                    'id' => '1234567890'
                   },
   '1234567891' => { 
                    'k1' => 'v1',
                    'k2' => 'v2',
                    'k3' => 'v3',
                    'k4' => 'v4',
                    'id' => '1234567891'
                   },
     ........
};
```

My limited understanding is that when I do `$hoh{$id} = %hash;` its inserting in a reference to %hash? What am I doing wrong? Also is there a more succint way to use my columns and data array's as key,value pairs into my %hash object?

-Thanks in advance,
Niru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a reference, you have to use `\`:

```
$hoh{$id} = \%hash;
```

`%hash` is the hash, not the reference to it. In scalar context, it returns the string `X/Y` wre X is the number of used buckets and Y the number of all the buckets in the hash (i.e. nothing useful).

Comment: You'd also have to pass a reference when calling `Dumper`.

Answer (score 2):

To get a reference to a hash variable, you need to use `\%hash` (as choroba said).

A more succinct way to assign values to columns is to assign to a [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), like this:

```
my %hoh = ();
while (my $line = <$tsv>) 
{
   chomp $line;
   my %hash;
   @hash{@columns} = split "\t", $line;
   $hoh{$hash{Id}} = \%hash;
}
print "dump: ", Dumper(\%hoh);
```

A hash slice (`@hash{@columns}`) means essentially the same thing as `($hash{$columns[0]}, $hash{$columns[1]}, $hash{$columns[2]}, ...)` up to however many columns you have.  By assigning to it, I'm assigning the first value from `split` to `$hash{$columns[0]}`, the second value to `$hash{$columns[1]}`, and so on.  It does exactly the same thing as your `while ... $iter` loop, just without the explicit loop (and it doesn't extract the `$id`).

There's no need to compare each `$k` to `'Id'` inside a loop; just store it in the hash as a normal field and extract it afterwards with `$hash{Id}`.  (Aside: Is your column header `Id` or `id`?  You use `Id` in your loop, but `id` in your expected output.)

If you don't want to keep the `Id` field in the individual entries, you could use [delete](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) (which removes the key from the hash and returns the value):

```
$hoh{delete $hash{Id}} = \%hash;
```

Comment: Sorry a little confused by how this works.

What goes on with:
@hash{@columns}. So convert %hash to an array and for each value in column iterate over the result of the split and sequentially insert into @hash?

also what happens here:  $hoh{$hash{Id}} = \%hash; How does it know to find the value for the id column i.ie 1234567890 and use that as the key for hoh?

Comment: Read the documentation on hash slices I linked to.  `@hash{@columns}` is like `($hash{$columns[0]}, $hash{$columns[1]}, $hash{$columns[2]}, ...)`.  It's not turning `%hash` into an array, it's just using the array sigil.

Comment: It knows how to find the id column because that's in `$hash{Id}`, which I use as the key when assigning the hashref to `$hoh{ $hash{Id} }`.

Comment: I see, I think I understand now. I did not notice the link in your post before, but reading it made more sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation included in Perl. The command `perldoc` is very helpful. You can also look at the [Perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org) webpage too.

One of the tutorials is a tutorial on [Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). It all help clarify a lot of your questions and explain about referencing and dereferencing.

I also recommend that you look at CPAN. This is an archive of various Perl modules that can do many various tasks. Look at [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm). This module will do exactly what you want, and even though it says "CSV", it works with tab separated files too.

You missed putting a slash in front of your hash you're trying to make a reference. You have:

```
$hoh{$id} = %hash;
```

Probably want:

```
$hoh{$id} = \%hash;
```

also, when you do a `Data::Dumper` of a hash, you should do it on a reference to a hash. Internally, hashes and arrays have similar structures when a Data::Dumper dump is done.

You have:

```
 print "dump: ", Dumper(%hoh);
```

You should have:

```
 print "dump: ", Dumper( \%hoh );
```

My attempt at the program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

use constant {
    FILE    => "test.txt",
};

open my $fh, "<", FILE;

#
# First line with headers
#

my $line = <$fh>;
chomp $line;
my @headers = split /\t/, $line;
my %hash_of_hashes;

#
# Rest of file
#
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my %line_hash;
    my @values = split /\t/, $line;
    for my $index ( ( 0..$#values ) ) {
        $line_hash{ $headers[$index] } = $values[ $index ];
    }
    $hash_of_hashes{ $line_hash{id} } = \%line_hash;
}

say Dumper \%hash_of_hashes;
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that CSV handles TSV as well, I didn't want to do manual convert step in between getting and opening the file. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you've got quotes in your TSV (which is uncommon), `Text::CSV` is overkill for parsing TSV.  `split` works just fine for that.

Comment: @cjm Look at my code that doesn't use `Text::CSV`. I have to read in my header, then match my header against each line, so I can build a hash. Text::CSV handles that for me. My code will fail if one line has more fields than another. I can handle it with `Text::CSV`. `Text::CSV` handles everything for me, and makes my programming job easier. The hardest thing about `Text::CSV` is it's incomplete documentation, and the fact it's not a standard module, so it may not be available for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should only store a reference to a variable if you do so in the last line before the variable goes go of scope. In your script, you declare `%hash` inside the while loop, so placing this statement as the last in the loop is safe:

```
$hoh{$id} = \%hash;
```

If it's not the last statement (or you're not sure it's safe), create an anonymous structure to hold the contents of the variable:

```
$hoh{$id} = { %hash };
```

This makes a copy of `%hash`, which is slower, but any subsequent changes to it will not effect what you stored.